# Ansible playbook not working when using roles in playbook

Tags: ansible, refactoring, roles

So, my playbook works fine when using this syntax:

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: true
  become_user: root
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local
  vars_files:
    - roles/docker_setup/vars/docker_vars.yml
    - roles/docker_setup/vars/aws_cred.yml
  vars:
    instance_ids:
      - "i-xxxxxxxxxxx"
  tasks:
    - include_role:
        name: docker_setup
        tasks_from: docker_tasks.yml
```

But I read that you can use this syntax which looks much easier to handle once I want to add new roles to the playbook:

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: true
  become_user: root
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local
  vars_files:
    - roles/docker_setup/vars/docker_vars.yml
    - roles/docker_setup/vars/aws_cred.yml
  vars:
    instance_ids:
      - "i-xxxxxxxxxxx"
  roles:
  - docker_setup
```

The difference is:

```
roles:
  - docker_setup
```

instead of

```
tasks:
  - include_role:
      name: docker_setup
      tasks_from: docker_tasks.yml
```

But once I try to run the playbook nothing happens:

```
sudo ansible-playbook docker_setup.yml --ask-vault-pass -i hosts --user devops --key-file /home/devops/.ssh/id_rsa
Vault password: 

PLAY [all] *************************************************************************************************************************************************

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************
```

Why is it that? Here is my tree of roles:

```
.
├── docker_setup
│   ├── handlers
│   │   └── main.yml
│   ├── tasks
│   │   └── docker_tasks.yml
│   └── vars
│       ├── aws_cred.yml
│       └── docker_vars.yml
└── user_host_create
    ├── handlers
    │   └── user_handlers.yml
    ├── tasks
    │   └── user_tasks.yml
    └── vars
        ├── user_password_vault.txt
        ├── user_password.yml
        └── user_vars.yml
```

and hosts file:

```
[webservers]
172.31.31.223
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the two options below is what file with the tasks is executed.

```yaml
  tasks:
    - include_role:
        name: docker_setup
        tasks_from: docker_tasks.yml
```

```yaml
  roles:
    - docker_setup
```

In the first case, it is explicitly *roles/docker_setup/tasks/docker_tasks.yml* (see [tasks_from](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_role_module.html#parameter-tasks_from)).

In the second case, it is *roles/docker_setup/tasks/main.yml* (see [Role directory structure](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#role-directory-structure)). This file is missing in the role. As a result, nothing is executed. You can fix it and create the file e.g.

```yaml
shell> cat roles/docker_setup/tasks/main.yml
- ansible.builtin.import_tasks: docker_tasks.yml
```

This would make the two options equivalent as to what tasks are executed. However, there will be other differences e.g. the scope of the variables, or inheritance of the tags. For details see [Using Roles](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#using-roles).